# using pumping lemma prove this language is not a context-free-language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

How can one prove that the language below is not context-free using the pumping lemma?

$$\{ a^i b^m a^j b^m a^k b^m \mid i,j,k,m \geq 0 \}$$

Comment: You cannot, since this language is context-free.

Comment: can explain more for your answer ? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: can you build a PDA/define a CFG for $b^mb^m$? If so, you can do it also for $a^*b^ma^*b^ma^*$.

Comment: sorry , i edited the language , so you said there is no possible way to prove ? @newbie

Comment: You cannot prove something which is false.

Comment: @newbie $b^mb^m$ is regular, yet $a^*b^ma^*b^ma^*$ isn't. So it's not so simple.

Comment: but in the question say prove this is not context - free , what's wrong ? 
does it depends on (m) condition ? what if changing m? ( for example m>=1)?

Comment: what do you mean about "it's not so simple"? so we can't prove ?please not that i changed the language .

Comment: The point of exercises such as this is to give you practice in using the pumping lemma. Whatever learning resource you're using (textbook, lecture notes, etc) probably already has several examples of using the pumping lemma. Us turning this exercises into another example for you probably won't help you a whole lot: the benefit comes from figuring it out yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that $a^* b^m a^* b^m a^* b^m$ is context-free. Applying the inverse of the homomorphism defined by $a\mapsto a$ and $b,c,d \mapsto b$, we see that $a^* (b+c+d)^m a^* (b+c+d)^m a^* (b+c+d)^m$ is also context-free. Intersecting with the regular language $b^* a c^* a d^*$, we see that $b^m a c^m a d^m$ is also context-free. Applying the homomorphism defined by $a \mapsto \epsilon$ and $\sigma \mapsto \sigma$ for $\sigma=b,c,d$, we see that $b^mc^md^m$ is also context-free. But we know that it's not context-free.

Comment: "using the pumping lemma"

Comment: Thanks but we can not change the alphabet into three other alphabet!

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am using the pumping lemma to prove that $b^mc^md^m$ is not context-free... :)

Comment: @shahingh Who said we cannot do that? In mathematics, we have the complete freedom to do anything which is mathematically valid.